# How do change the program automatically started when I insert a CD?

Tags: cd, media

When I insert a CD Rhythmbox automatically starts. How can I disable this and make a different program start when a CD is inserted?

I have looked at System Settings and cannot find any options for altering which program is opened when a CD is inserted.

Comment: What is Ubuntu version?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

> Edit -> Plugins.
>
> Select Status Icon, click the 'configure' button.
>
> Choose the "never shown" option for notifications.